# Dynamic Formset with crispy forms and django-dynamic-formset not working

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, formset

I'm trying to use the app django-dynamic-formset to allow users to add more than one media object at the end of a form.

I'm following the demo here. 
https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst

I managed to get this to work but then changed to using crispy form and it's no longer working.

The "add another" text isn't appearing aver the first inline formset.

The template looks like this.

```
    <form id="dtuForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="." method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% crispy form %}
    <fieldset class=""  id="formaddtest" >

        {% for formset in inlines %}
        <div id = "media_object">

            {% for subform in formset.forms %}
            {{ formset.management_form }}

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Add Link / Downloadable File</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {% crispy subform %}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>

    {% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
    </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

I'm starting to suspect that I'm not putting the media_object selector in the right place but I'm not sure where to put it now that I'm using crispy forms so any help or pointers is useful to me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Also can you post your javascript with the working non-crispy version?